# How to get current touch point and previous touch point in UIPanGestureRecognizer method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer, uitouch, touchesbegan

I am new to iOS, I am using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in my project. In which I have a requirement to get current touch point and previous touch point when I am dragging the view. I am struggling to get these two points.

If I use `touchesBegan` method Instead of using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, I could get these two points by the following code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previous=[[touches anyObject]previousLocationInView:self];
}
```

I need to get these two points in `UIPanGestureRecognizer` event fire method. How can I achieve this? please guide me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this:

```
CGPoint currentlocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
```

Store previous location by setting current location if not found and adding current location everytime.

```
previousLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 4):

When you link an [`UIPanGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to an IBAction, the action will get called on every change. The gesture recognizer also provides a property called `state` which indicates if it's the first `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, the last `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` or just an event between `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`.

To solve your problem, try it like the following:

```
- (IBAction)panGestureMoveAround:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        myVarToStoreTheBeganPosition = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
    } else if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
       CGPoint myNewPositionAtTheEnd = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
       // and now handle it ;)
    }
}
```

You may also have a look at the method called [`translationInView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPanGestureRecognizer/translationInView%3a).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to store anything you can also do this :

```
let location = panRecognizer.location(in: self)
let translation = panRecognizer.translation(in: self)
let previousLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x - translation.x, y: location.y - translation.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate your pan gesture recognizer as follows:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
```

Then you should add panRecognizer to your view:

```
[aView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

The `- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer` method will be called while the user interacts with the view. In handlePan: you can get the point touched like this:

```
CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:aView];
```

You can also get the state of the panRecognizer:

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    //do something
} else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
   //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in UITouch to get the previous touch in the view

- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view;
- (CGPoint)previousLocationInView:(UIView *)view;