# Get the start point and end point of the UIPanGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: swift, uipangesturerecognizer, swift2

I'm using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on a project, and I want to take the starting point and the end point.

I tried to do for `touchesBegin`, but did not get a code that does what I need.

**How can I get the start point and end point of the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13270442/1801544 ?

Comment: @Larme I am new in programming for iOS, and Swift started in two months. I still can not understand well the Objective-C. You could post an example in Swift?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your case, you might want to include the code inside my function into your IBAction for the panGesture. Here I've created a view, but otherwise you would just be referring to `self.view` instead of `view`.

```
var view = UIView()

func panGestureMoveAround(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

 var locationOfBeganTap: CGPoint

 var locationOfEndTap: CGPoint

 if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

     locationOfBeganTap = gesture.locationInView(view)

 } else if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

    locationOfEndTap = gesture.locationInView(view)
 }

}
```

Comment: I have a use case where the location at Began time doesn't really tell me the starting point, especially if I put down the finger (normal speed), then pan quickly. Seems like the pan gesture records the location only when it fires, i.e. probably after another gesture recognizer like "tap" failed.

Comment: Well, here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6950812/255585. The Began state can have a non 0,0 translation, so it needs to be substracted from the Began position to get the real starting point.